# Button with dropdown - onBlur is triggered with tab key, despite still being focused

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, keyboard-events, onblur

I have a button with a dropdown.
On the outer div container, I set a onBlur function where the dropdown will collapse when the component is not in focus anymore.

I am able to use the tab key and press `enter` key to expand the dropdown. However, when I press the tab key again to go down the list in the dropdown, the dropdown collapses.

When I remove the collapse function on the onBlur prop, I no longer get this problem thus I am able to tab down the list of items in the dropdown. However, this prevents me from being able to collapse the dropdown by clicking or tabbing anywhere outside of the component.

Why is it that the onBlur function is being triggered when I tab down the items in the list? Surely I am still focused in the component and it shouldn't do the onBlur.

```
      <div 
        className={containerClass} 
        onBlur={() => this.setState({ currentHeight: 0 })} <----- issue
      >

        <div className="dropdown__button__row">
            <button
              type="button" 
              className={`dropdown__button__container ${buttonClass}`}
              style={{background: this.color(buttonVariant)}} 
              onClick={this.handleRowExpand}
              onKeyPress={this.handleRowExpand}
              ref={(ref) => { this.button = ref }}
            >
                <div className="button__inner__container">
                  <p className="dropdown__button__name">
                    {children}
                  </p>
                  <div className="dropdown__chevron-icon">
                    <Chevron
                      direction="down"
                      color="#ffffff"
                      width="12"
                      height="8"
                      className="dropdown__button__chevron"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div 
         className={answerClass} 
         style={contentStyle} 
         ref={(ref) => { this.expandRow = ref }}
        >
          <div 
            className="expand__content" 
            ref={(ref) => { this.expandContent = ref }}
           >
            <div className="content">

              <div className="dropdown__button__expandable__container">
              {
                options.map(option => {
                  return (
                    <div 
                      className="dropdown__button__list-item" 
                      key={option.id}
                    >
                      <div className="dropdown__list__container">
                        <Paragraph size="medium">
                          <a className="dropdown__list__anchor" href= 
                           {option.url}>{option.label}
                          </a>
                        </Paragraph>
                      </div>
                      <div className='chevron__container'>
                        <Chevron
                          color='#000000'
                          direction='right'
                          width="12"
                          height="12"
                          className="mark"
                        />
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )
                })
              }
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Pressing the `tab` key will select the next `element` and not the `list items` of your dropdown, which will trigger your `collapse` function as the element loose the focus. Navigating through `options` is possible with arrow down.

Comment: I don't understand what your desired behavior, you want onBlur to trigger the collapse except for tab event?

Comment: onBlur is being triggered when I tab into the list item in the dropdown. This is despite the fact that the div is still focused and the tab still remains in the dropdown, except I can't see the blue outline (focus) because the dropdown is collapsed. @randomSoul navigating through the options with arrow down is not possible. The onBlur function encompasses everything including the actual button and the dropdown. So tabbing into the dropdown should mean it's still focused.